# how can i hide the Scrollbar from the vf page inside the salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

i have one VF page which i am using in desktop as well as salesforce1 but in salesforce one this page contains scroll bar how can i hide the scroll bar from the vf page in salesforce1 context.

Comment: Can you post some code here for the reference? Your page might have a <div> tag with maximum width/height defined in it. You can change that height/width.

Answer (score 1):

Following things you can do:

1) DO not provide width/height to vf page top container (probably `div`).

2) Make sure that any component inside the container does not have width/height greater than top container

4) If width/height is perfect. Make sure margin and padding to top container set to `0` and inner components must not have margin or padding exceeding the top container width/height.

You can follow following post while creating vf page. They have provided some css for creating salesforce like look and feel pages:

http://intmist.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/salesforce1-look-and-feel-customise-visualforce-pages-for-salesforce1/